# Breaking a kubernetes pod circular readiness dependency

Tags: kubernetes, grpc, kubernetes-pod, circular-dependency, readinessprobe

Suppose I have two deployments, `D_a` and `D_b` and they each have a replica of 1. Ideally this would get me two running pods `P_a` and `P_b`.

Now suppose both `P_a` and `P_b` contain gRPC services which periodically ping each other to establish their readinesss state.

I now have a circular dependency between the two and I will never be able to get them ready as each one of them won't be ready for the other one to become ready.

Is this an anti-pattern or perhaps I am completely missing the point of readiness probes?

How would I break this loop? Thank you in advance!

Comment: If A depends on B, B should not depend on A.   If B 'needs' something from A ("something-x")....."something-x" should be moved to C.

Comment: The other question is: do we *really* want our services to be taken out of the load balancer, just because a downstream service fails? Maybe it's better reporting an error to the client/frontend instead of "going offline".

Comment: @granadaCoder you raise an excellent point. I guess it is a microservice architecture issue if there's a circular dependency.

Comment: @Turing85 thanks this is another valid point! Especially when one has gRPC microservices with many endpoints then the failure of a dependency used for a portion of them should not prevent the others from working.